# How do I run a JS file from another JS file?

Tags: javascript, powershell, npm, prompt

I am building a game inside the console, I'm using an NPM package called "prompts", and it asks from the user for the game, "What OS do you want to run?" and returns as JSON. For example if you selected "OS 1" it would return { Bootup: "StartOS1" }. What I want to do is basically to have an if statement like this:

```js
if(Bootup == "StartOS1") {
 // The code to run another JS file here.
}
```

But I don't know what to put.

I've tried to do this with a NPM package called shelljs, which executes stuff in the shell:

```js
const shell = require('shelljs')

if(Bootup == "StartOS1") {
  shell.exec('node OS1.js')
}
```

What this did was make my shell stuck on a blank line forever, and I had to restart it. This shows an example of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Why did you tag [tag:PowerShell]?

Comment: Eh, idk. Bc the solution i tried was related to pwsh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`shell.exec('node OS1.js')` is a synchronous function that will block your program. For instance, if your js file is waiting on an event, it might block your functions indefinitely. Try `child_process`'s `exec()` method. This should help:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

exec('node OS1.js', (e, stdout, stde) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${e}`);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  console.error(`stderr: ${stde}`);
});
```

There are also a couple of other methods you can use, but this one reads the js file as a string then executes it via the other synchronous `eval` function. Though I heard it's not the best practice when it comes to security.

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./node OS1.js', 'utf8', function(e, file) {
  if (e) {
    console.error(e);
    return;
  }
  eval(file);
});
```